# Create one element Set the same way (if applicable) as create single element list

Tags: java, set

To create a single item list we can use `Collections.singletonList(s)`, Are there any way to create a single item `Set`

Comment: `Collections.singleton(s)`

Comment: Or, since java 9, `Set.of(s)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. Just use `Collections.singleton(s)`.

As per [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#singleton(T)):

> Returns an immutable set containing only the specified object. The returned set is serializable.

(I know the name isn't very suggestive)